# Error on attempting to move and shrink an Ubuntu partition using GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I like to add the unallocated space to the NTFS `/dev/sda2` partition. However I get following error when I move `/dev/sda3` to the right, so that unallocated space can be added to `/dev/sda2`.

I am dual booting. I'm running XP on the NTFS partition `dev/sda2`, and an Ubuntu desktop on `/dev/sda6`.

Any idea what is the issue here?

> ```
> ====================================
>
> GParted 0.12.1 --enable-libparted-dmraid
>
> Libparted 2.3
> Move /dev/sda3 to the right and shrink it from 78.82 GiB to 53.99 GiB  00:00:01    ( ERROR )
>
> calibrate /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
>
> path: /dev/sda3
> start: 59,410,430
> end: 224,701,154
> size: 165,290,725 (78.82 GiB)
> shrink partition from 78.82 GiB to 53.99 GiB  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
>
> old start: 59,410,430
> old end: 224,701,154
> old size: 165,290,725 (78.82 GiB)
> requested start: 111,472,640
> requested end: 224,700,415
> requested size: 113,227,776 (53.99 GiB)
> libparted messages    ( INFO )
>
> Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
>
> ========================================
> ```

Comment: I think you need to replace `/dev/sda6` in your question by `/dev/sda3`. Am I right? If so, edit your question.

Comment: Could you open a terminal and include the output of `sudo fdisk -l` in your question?

Comment: upload gparted screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into windows and then use [EASEUS PARTITION MASTER](http://www.partition-tool.com/) to add unallocated space to your NTFS partition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do the two tasks separately ?  I mean, first resize the partition. Verify if the operation was correct. Then close gparted, turn off your PC, turn on again, and try to move the partition.